# Passed data inside event — is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, mousewheel, args

Have no errors, just do not work. Addition of `this` has no affecting too.

```
input( type="number" v-model="myData" @wheel="wheelIt($event, myData, myMethod)" )

...

methods:
{
    wheelIt ( event, data, func )
    {
        if ( event.deltaY < 0 )
        {
            data += 1
            func()
            event.preventDefault()
        }
        if ( event.deltaY > 0 )
        {
            data -= 1
            func()
            event.preventDefault()
        }
    },
```

Hardcoded wheel event works just fine, but I need parameterise it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is not increment inside function, but in event directly

```
@wheel="wheelIt($event, myData += 1, myMethod)"
```